# DNN 5.2.3 Stored Procedures executing numerous times during page loads

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, dotnetnuke

After tracing the DB activity from a DNN 5.2.3 site I noticed that there are numerous identical calls to the database whilst loading the home page for the first time (afterwards the caching works successfully).

```
//Procedure : Number of executions

exec dbo.aspnet_Membership_GetUserByName @ApplicationName=N'DotNetNuke',@UserName=N'MYDOMAIN\ME',@UpdateLastActivity=0,@CurrentTimeUtc='2010-03-24 10:04:15:223' : 22

exec dbo.GetPortalAliasByPortalID @PortalID=0 : 15

exec dbo.GetUserProfile @UserID=8 : 11

exec dbo.GetUser @PortalID=0,@UserID=8 : 10

exec dbo.GetDatabaseVersion  : 2

exec dbo.GetUserCountByPortal @PortalId=0: 2

exec dbo.GetDesktopModules  : 2

exec dbo.KB_XMod_Forms_List @PortalId=0 : 2

exec dbo.KB_XMod_Templates_List @PortalId=0,@TemplateType=-1 : 2
```

Why so many duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are not working under SuperUser account and "Host settings\Advanced\Performance setting" is set to "Heavy Caching".

Comment: I'm logging in as an Administrator and it is set to heavy caching. I don't imagine caching will help when it comes to initial user authentication.

Comment: I'm not sure about Administrator, but under "host" account DNN performance drops significantly due to repetitive DB queries.